# How to either completely remove SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation or repair it?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've installed MSSQL server correctly, then I took some wrong turns and I'm now left in a pretty undesirable state. I wanted to change the server instance to another drive, so I uninstalled SQL server and all of it's features from the `Programs and Features` control panel.

Now when I tried to install a new instance, I got a few errors, but it still installed most of them:
[image]

Then I tried to run a repair, which I figured would fix things, but it throws an exception about not being able to read something from the CD (tried more than once always the same exception)

> Error 1316.A network error occurred while attempting to read from the
>   file R:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SSCERuntime_x86-enu.msi

, and it fails to repair a few of the features:

[image]

And I don't have the server instance installed either. So I'm left with no MSSQLMS, no server instance, and no happiness. What would be the best course of action here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was a known issue in a older version.  You may want to try the workaround, which involves manually removing the SQL Server Compact Edition components from Add/Remove Programs and then running Repair.

**You may receive "Error 1316.A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file Path\SSCERuntime-ENU.msi" error message when you repair an instance SQL Server 2008**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970876

Following are the steps involved in one workaround:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/363055/sql-2008-x64-repair-error

1. Remove SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1  manually from the Add/remove programs. The  is a placeholder for the language of installation (e.g., English for an English installation, etc.)
2. Repair SQL Server 2008-11-24

After repair, SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1  is re-installed on the system. In case of any problems with re-installing SQL Server Compact it can be downloaded and installed from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DC614AEE-7E1C-4881-9C32-3A6CE53384D9&displaylang=en or alternatively SSCERuntime.msi can be installed from the SQL Server 2008 installation media from the ...Servers\Setup folder.

Comment: It's in my DVD drive, but that file didn't even exist, `R:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SSCERuntime.msi` does though.

Comment: Seems like this was a known issue a while back.  I updated the answer with additional information.